# How to delete all items in a doubly linked list that match a certain value?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have an assignment where I have to write a function that can delete any part of a doubly linked list that there's a value with a predetermined input. I worked on this for quite some time, and I can't find anything else wrong with the code I have written. The assignment says as follows:

> Write a C++ function to delete nodes in a linked list. The function takes two arguments - the head of the linked list and the value to be deleted. It should delete all nodes which contain the value to be deleted. It should return the head of the linked list.
>
> The linked list structure:
>
> ```
> struct node
> {
>     int value;
>     node *next;
>     node *prev;
> };
> ```

```
node *DeleteNode(node *head, int value){
node *tmp=head;
while(tmp!=NULL){
    if(tmp->value==value){
        if(tmp==head){
            head=head->next;
            head->prev=NULL;
            delete tmp;
            tmp=head;
        }
        else if(tmp->next==NULL){
            node *temp=tmp;
            temp->prev->next=NULL;
            delete tmp;
            tmp=temp;
        }
        else{
            node *node1=tmp;
            node1->prev->next=node1->next;
            node1->next->prev=node1->prev;
            delete tmp;
            tmp=node1;
        }
    }
    tmp=tmp->next;
}
return head;}
```

So, when it runs the test of

> 1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4

and needs to delete all 3s, it gets a result of

> 1 <-> 2 <-> 4

which is correct. It works with other examples that need to remove items at the head, as well as examples that need to remove the tail. It has worked with every desired function....BESIDES...

> 2 <-> 2 <-> 2 <-> 2 <-> 65 <-> 83

where the 2s need to be deleted. It is only getting a result of

> 2<-> 65 <-> 83

So an extra 2 is being left in for some reason. Any guesses? I have provided everything I was provided for this question. I think the issue may be in my section for deleting middle items in the doubly linked list, but I'm completely lost. Thanks so much!

Comment: I do not grok what's happening in `else if(tmp->next==NULL){` `temp` points to same as `tmp`. You `delete tmp`, so `tmp` and `temp` both point at garbage, then you assign the garbage pointer `temp` back to `tmp`. This will go boom at `tmp=tmp->next;`

Comment: Thinking on that a bit more, I think you can cheat like hell since you're at the end of the list. `tmp->prev->next=NULL; delete tmp; return head;`

Comment: All three answers bring important and different details to the table. Recommend taking them all into account.

Comment: @tschadius  Do not be hurry. Even if you will implement the solutions shown in the answers your function will contain a bug.:) As usually only my solution is correct.:)

Comment: You really should be using [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), which is a standardized double-linked list implementation. Then you can use [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`std::list::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) (the so-called [Erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)) to remove all elements of the same value (or any criteria you want using `std::remove_if()` instead).

Comment: @RemyLebeau std::list has its own method remove_if.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: good catch, I missed that. [std::list::remove, remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addition to Barry's answer:

```
node *temp=tmp;
temp->prev->next=NULL;
delete tmp;
tmp=temp;
```

This will set an alias `temp` for your current node `tmp`, then set the `next` pointer of your previous node to NULL, delete your current node and set your tmp-pointer to `temp`, but thats just an alias for your just deleted node. You probably want `node *temp=tmp->prev;` to set your tmp to the new last element.

What probably causes your error is, that regardles of your comparison with value, you call

```
tmp=tmp->next;
```

at the end, going to your next node. You should wrap this in an else block to only execute if your value does not match.

Comment: This was it! I wrapped the tmp=tmp->next bit at the end into an else block and it functioned. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This looks suspect (adding some spaces):

```
node* node1 = tmp;
node1->prev->next = node1->next;
node1->next->prev = node1->prev;
delete tmp;
tmp = node1;
```

`node1` is just an alias for `tmp`. It doesn't actually serve any other purpose. Then you `delete` `tmp` and assign it to `node1` - which is precisely what you just deleted!

You probably want to do:

```
tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
node* prev = tmp->prev;
delete tmp;
tmp = prev;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when your initial head node matches the value.

In this you set the next node to be the new head and get rid of the old one and then set tmp to be the new head,

```
if(tmp==head){
        head=head->next;
        head->prev=NULL;
        delete tmp;
        tmp=head;
 }
```

Then when you exit the if statements you set

```
tmp = tmp-> next
```

So in your if block you set your current node to be the next node and then delete what used to be your current node, then when you exit the if statement you move down to the next node again, effectively skipping the new head node altogether.

Comment: Yes, this explained it. Thank you for the help, I put the tmp=tmp->next into an else block and the problem was fixed. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

When a double-linked list is defined then usually a separate structure is defined that contains two pointers: one pointer to the head of the list and other pointer to the tail of the list. For example

```
struct list
{
    node *head = nullptr;
    node *tail = nullptr;
    //...
};
```

Also inside the structure member functions are declared that process the list.

Nevertheless if to use your approach then the function that removes all nodes that have values equal to a given value can look as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int value;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};

void display( node *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next )
    {
        std::cout << head->value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

node * AppendNode( node *head, int value )
{
    node *tmp = new node { value, nullptr, nullptr };

    if ( !head )
    {
        head = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *prev = head;
        while ( prev->next ) prev = prev->next;
        tmp->prev = prev;
        prev->next = tmp;
    }

    return head;
}

node * DeleteNode( node *head, int value )
{
    for ( node *current = head; current; )
    {
        if ( current->value == value )
        {
            node *tmp = current;

            if ( current->next )
            {
                current->next->prev = current->prev;
            }

            if ( current->prev )
            {
                current->prev->next = current->next;
                current = current->next;
            }
            else
            {
                head = current->next;
                current = head;
            }

            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }            
    }

    return head;
}    

int main()
{
    node *head = nullptr;

    for ( int x : { 2, 2, 2, 2, 65, 83 } ) head = AppendNode( head, x );

    display( head );

    head = DeleteNode( head, 2 );

    display( head );

    head = DeleteNode( head, 83 );

    display( head );

    head = DeleteNode( head, 65 );

    display( head );
}
```

Its output is

```
2 2 2 2 65 83 
65 83 
65
```

Comment: This answer brings up, via a side channel, the question of whether a linked list implementation should be responsible for or even capable of "delete if" behaviour without assistance. I'm thinking no.

Comment: @user4581301 It is possible that I have not understood your comment. So my answer can be irrelevant.:) Nevertheless std::list has method remove_if.

Comment: You understood. It would seem I have a differing of opinions with the Standards committee.